# Access JCas Annotation list

Tags: apache, annotations, uima

I am developing an `Apache UIMA v2` application to annotate documents.
I developed properly the `process()` method because I obtain the correct annotations (tested with debug and `UIMA CAS Visual Debugger`).

My application consists in a simple instantiation of the `JCas` object and the process of a document, i.e. a simple string in this case. Here's the code:

```
public class MainProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        XMLInputSource in = new XMLInputSource("desc/dictionaryDescriptor.xml");
        ResourceSpecifier specifier = UIMAFramework.getXMLParser().parseResourceSpecifier(in);
        AnalysisEngine ae = UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(specifier);

        JCas jcas = ae.newJCas();

        jcas.setDocumentText("prova di a@gmail.com, timido, word, excel. ");

        ae.process(jcas);
        processResults(jcas);

        ae.destroy();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidXMLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ResourceInitializationException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AnalysisEngineProcessException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static  void  processResults(JCas jcas) {
    System.out.println("Done!");
    // TODO read annotations from jcas
}
}
```

If I add a breakpoint inside the `processResults()` method I can see the content of  `jcas` and the list of annotation:
[image: debug jcas object]

I want to access to the `SubTypes` list in the `AnnotationIndex` object, **without taking care of the class type**.

Here is an example through a specific type:

```
AnnotationIndex<Annotation> programIndex = jcas.getAnnotationIndex(Programma.type);
    Iterator programIter = programIndex.iterator();

    while(programIter.hasNext()) {
        Programma p = (Programma) programIter.next();
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it once you have that list?

Comment: I want to iterate that list and then check the type. Do you think that it's useless and it's better to use the iterator like I did? (I'm adding the code right now)

Comment: Btw. you might want to have a look at uimaFIT (https://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#ugr.tools.uimafit.casutil) - in particular if you are using UIMA v2. If you are using UIMA v3, you may want to look here: https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-current/version_3_users_guide.pdf (Section 4 - "Select" framework)

Comment: I'm using UIMA v2. Do you think that is a good idea to switch to UIMA v3? I'm new to UIMA so I can't understand the impact of the differences. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to be compatible with most other UIMA code / UIMA components (e.g. DKPro Core) that are presently out there, it is a good idea to stick with UIMAv2 for a bit longer. UIMAv3 has a new internal data management, better support for generics and streams, but it is also largely API compatible with v2, so that the migration should not be a big issue when you eventually do it.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if the APIs provided by UIMAv3 are a big improvement that simplifies the work or if to getting started is good to continue with UIMAv2.

Comment: If you use UIMAv2 together with uimaFIT, the uimaFIT (J)CasUtil "select" methods are pretty much as convenient as the UIMAv3 "select API". In fact, uimaFIT served as a role model for the v3 select API. In any case, you may want to use uimaFIT when you are writing your own UIMA components to profit from its parameter injection functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JCasUtil to extract the annotations of the JCas:

```
JCasUtil.select(jCas, Annotation.class).stream()....
```

and with the getType() method of the annotation you can check for the type of the annotation.